# My triac turns on when gate attached to vcc (good)... but also when connected to ground (bad)

Tags: ac, power-electronics, triac, el-wire

I'm still really new at working with triacs and understanding them, but I want to make a circuit that allows a microcontroller to turn on/off an AC signal (very low power, not mains, don't worry) to blink and sequence EL wire.

I sketched up this circuit:
[image: circuit]

and tried to build a simple version of it. BAT +/- is a 3-4V (depending on charge level) DC battery, AC1 & AC2 are the output of an inverter fed by the same battery. the loads are connected across OUT1A/OUT1B, OUT2A/OUT2B, etc.

my issue is that when I connect the gate pin of one of these triacs to VCC, the el wire turns on (great!), but it also turns on when I connect it to ground (bad!). if I leave it floating, the el wire is off.

did I do something stupid here? I'm still learning the nuances of these things and I'm not sure where I messed up.

thanks so much!

Comment: "did I do something stupid here?" - you have the TRIACs wired up wrong? Please show us a photo of your setup.

Comment: don't have the setup on me physically until later today, unfortunately. at worst I suppose I could have mixed up MT1 and MT2 on the triac -- would that produce this behavior? FWIW, I was trying to be really careful about this and triple-checked the datasheet to make sure the pins were correct

Comment: Define what you mean by " AC signal (very low power, not mains, don't worry)".   What is this AC signal and is it DC biased relative to ground???  (Or does it swing fully +/- from ground equally in each direction?)   This project may better be done with transistors depending on that.

Comment: Can you show link to Triac datasheet?

Answer (score 1):

If you connect the gate pin directly to Vcc you'll likely destroy the triac. After that, who knows..

Comment: sorry, connected to VCC through a resistor (R1, R2, R3 on the circuit diagram)